# How to find a file by name in the filter tree in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, filter

Suppose I know that a file of a certain name is in a project in Visual C++ 2010 Express.  I can see it in the "Show All Files" list.  Is there any way to find out where it lurks in the "filter" hierarchy, short of laboriously opening each folder and looking?  (As an example of what I would wish for, in Xcode one can right-click on a file and choose "Reveal in Group Tree".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VsCommands is an extension to Visual Studio that has a ['locate in solution'](http://vscommands.com/2010/07/02/locate-in-solution/) option for a file that is already open in your editor.

Comment: I downloaded VSCommands 2010, and the installer said "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products".  Does that mean that it doesn't work with Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Comment: I found a message saying that the Express edition does not support extensions.  I've clarified my question.